# how to calculate two aggregate fields in different queries : 'dict' object has no attribute 'variable-name' django

Tags: python, django

i need to subtraction between two aggregate fields in two different queries :

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
    #others
class ModelB(models.Model):
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    #others

paid_price = ModelA.objects.filter(status=True).annotate(
    total_paid = Sum(F('price')),
    #some more fields
        ).aggregate(
            paid = Sum(F('total_paid'))
            #some more fields
        )

paid_costs = ModelB.objects.filter(status=True).annotate(
    total_cost = Sum(F('cost')),
    #some more fields
        ).aggregate(
            t_cost= Sum(F('total_paid')),
            #some more fields
        )
```

i need to calculate `t_cost` with `paid` i tried this `final_result = paid_price.paid - paid_costs.t_cost`

but raised this errror:

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'paid '

is there a way to achieve it ?
**note** : the models dont have connection between each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate results are dictionaries, you need to get the calculated values by key

```
final_result = paid_price['paid'] - paid_costs['t_cost']
```

Note: an annotation on a field that is part of the model will not do anything unless you have some grouping (which I can't see in your queries)

Remove the `Sum` if you just want to rename the field in the query

```
ModelA.objects.annotate(
    total_paid=F('price')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [**`aggregate()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.aggregate) method ***always*** results a ***dict*** result.

> Returns a dictionary of aggregate values (averages, sums, etc.) calculated over the `QuerySet`.

so, the expression should be,

```
final_result = paid_price['paid'] - paid_costs['t_cost']
```